# How to Configure jenkins email notification for some commercial email services?

Tags: jenkins, configuration

For configuring jenkins email notification with some corporate email server or commercial email services.

How we can get mail server setting details like mail server name, port number, using SSL, etc. for such email services?

Comment: You can do the smtp configuration in Jenkins - Configuration - Extended E-mail Notification block.

Comment: Ask your mail provider.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider these two Jenkins plugins for it:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

The first one is mostly basic and the second one is extended for additional user customizations. All necessary instructions regarding configuration, etc are described there.

> > > How we can get mail server setting details like mail server name, port number, using SSL, etc. for such email services?

I am afraid that the best approach here is either refer to your system administrator who is resposible for it or contact with the provider who provides mail services.